# Google Dataflow Unable to get application default credentials

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam-io

I am writting sample application to consume messages from pub sub using apache databeam dataflow.
I have configured the following items

1. `buckets (staging and temp folders)`
2. `pub sub`
3. `service princpal having permission for both`

But when I am running the pipeline , I am getting the error on starting itself.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataflowRunner requires gcpTempLocation, but failed to retrieve a value from PipelineOptions
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions(DataflowRunner.java:287)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build(InstanceBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions(PipelineRunner.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create(Pipeline.java:155)
    at com.demo.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error constructing default value for gcpTempLocation: tempLocation is not a valid GCS path, gs://card_pipeline_bucket/temp/. 
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create(GcpOptions.java:377)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create(GcpOptions.java:355)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.returnDefaultHelper(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:678)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.getDefault(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:619)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getGcpTempLocation(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions(DataflowRunner.java:285)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get application default credentials. Please see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for details on how to specify credentials. This version of the SDK is dependent on the gcloud core component version 2015.02.05 or newer to be able to get credentials from the currently authorized user via gcloud auth.
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.auth.NullCredentialInitializer.throwNullCredentialException(NullCredentialInitializer.java:60)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.auth.NullCredentialInitializer$NullCredentialHttpUnsuccessfulResponseHandler.handleResponse(NullCredentialInitializer.java:53)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ChainingHttpRequestInitializer$3.handleResponse(ChainingHttpRequestInitializer.java:106)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1059)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:525)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:466)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:576)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.ResilientOperation.retry(ResilientOperation.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.getBucket(GcsUtil.java:684)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.verifyBucketAccessible(GcsUtil.java:675)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.util.GcsUtil.verifyBucketAccessible(GcsUtil.java:630)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.verifyPathIsAccessible(GcsPathValidator.java:83)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.validateOutputFilePrefixSupported(GcsPathValidator.java:53)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create(GcpOptions.java:374)
    ... 15 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have verified the service principal used is allowed for pub sub and buckets. Followed the approach given by GitHubGist
[maciekrb/PubSub to BigQuery using Dataflow](https://gist.github.com/maciekrb/9c73cb94a258e177e023dba9049dda13)